# Text inside ttk.button is not centered

Tags: python, tkinter, button, text, ttkbootstrap

*I created a button using `ttk.button` and put text on it, but the text is not centered inside the button, I have already tried using `ttk.Style()` but it seems that it is not being applied, what could be happening?*

```
from textwrap import fill
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import bgcolor, heading, width
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class APP:

    def __init__(self):
        # Criando a janela principal
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Test")
        self.root.geometry("1080x600")  # Define o tamanho da janela
        # Impede o redimensionamento da janela
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        # Carregando a imagem existente
        background_image = Image.open("background.png")

        # Convertendo a imagem para o formato Tkinter PhotoImage
        self.background_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)

        # Criando um rótulo com a imagem como plano de fundo
        self.background_label = tk.Label(
            self.root, image=self.background_photo)
        self.background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        style_button = ttk.Style()
        style_button.theme_use("litera")
        style_button.configure("TButton", padx=5, pady=10, anchor="w")

        # Criando o frame do Dataset
        self.dataset_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, height=10)
        self.dataset_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=5)

        self.dataset_label = ttk.Label(
            self.dataset_frame, text="Dataset: ", bootstyle="inverse-primary", width=47)
        self.dataset_label.configure(font=("Arial", 14, "bold"))
        self.dataset_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill="x")

        self.directory_entry = ttk.Entry(
            self.dataset_frame, width=55, bootstyle="primary")
        self.directory_entry.place(
            relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relheight=0.9, anchor="center")

        self.directory_button = ttk.Button(
            self.dataset_frame, style="TButton", text="Selecionar")
        self.directory_button.place(
            relx=0.92, rely=0.5, relheight=0.8, anchor="center")

        # Criando o frame do preview
        self.preview_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.preview_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=5)

        self.preview_label = ttk.Label(
            self.preview_frame, text="Preview: ", bootstyle="inverse-primary", width=48)
        self.preview_label.configure(font=("Arial", 14, "bold"))
        self.preview_label.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both")

        # Inicia o loop principal da aplicação
        self.root.mainloop()


# Inicializa a aplicação
app = APP()
```

An example of how it looks, I wanted to center the text inside the button:

[image: An example of how it looks, I wanted to center the text inside the button]

Comment: Try removing `relheight=0.8` from `self.directory_button.place(...)`.  Also remove `style_button.configure("Tbutton", ...)`.